# Почему в одном случае результат получается в кавычках, а в другом без?

Tags: python, python-3.x, idle

язык python 3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 21:26:53) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
```

```
>>> bottles = 99
>>> base = ''
>>> base = base + 'current inventory: '
>>> base = base + str(bottles)
>>> print(base)
current inventory: 99
>>> bottles = 99
>>> base = ''
>>> base += 'current inventory: '
>>> base += str(bottles)
>>> base
'current inventory: 99'
>>>
```

Comment: В первом  случае строка печатается в консоли при помощи print, во втором -- выводится переменная `base`, кавычки указывают на строковый тип.

Answer (score 2):

Фактически, происходит примерно следующее:

```py
text = 'hello world'
print(str(text))
print(repr(text))
```

Вывод:

```
hello world
'hello world'
```

При печати объекта на нём вызывается `str` и результат выводится на печать. При этом печатается просто содержимое объекта, сами внешние кавычки в строке не содержатся и они не печатаются.

А вот при выводе объекта в интерактивной среде на самом деле вызывается метод `repr` и вот он то и добавляет кавычки к выводу, чтобы внести ясность, что показываемый объект - это строка.

Comment: спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

Вызывая функцию `print` вы говорите вывести значение переменной `base`.
Если вы просто пишите `base` - интерпретатор `Python` **показывает вам содержимое переменной**, т.е. делает так, чтобы перед *выводом* вы подставили (к примеру) `base1 =`  и у вас создалась переменная `base1` с тем же самым значением.

Comment: спасибо за помощь